# Crystal Reports Server folder backup

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

In SAP Crystal Server Java BI Launch Pad inside Documents > Folders > Public Folders I've created a new folder and imported (many many) reports to it.

Don't know what happened to the server but all of it's settings have been reset, and the folder is no longer there - so I need to recreate it, and import all my reports back (a proccess that takes a long time since I need to import one report at a time).

Is there a way to backup/export that folder as a backup? so next time a thing like this happens I can just restore my folder with all the reports from that backup file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Promotion Management* (aka *LifeCycle Management* or LCM as it was known in previous iterations) to export any set of objects (documents, universes, …). You can access this (web) application via the CMC.

Instead of live-to-live promotion (i.e. from one live system to another live system), you'd choose for a live-to-BIAR promotion, where the selected content would be exported to an `.lcmbiar` file. An  `.lcmbiar` file is basically a ZIP archive which consists of the actual objects (e.g. reports, …) as you would find them on the FRS share as well as metadata information.

To restore an `.lcmbiar` file, you'd upload it back to the server through Promotion Management.

Alternatively, you could use the CLI to generate the file, without having to go through the web interface. This is especially useful if your promotion job consists of a very large (100+) number of objects or the selection criteria are quite specific.

You can find more information on Promotion Management in *Business Intelligence Platform Administrator Guide*, chapter 15.